# Unable to parse XML from PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, soap

I was not able to find same problem, for that reason I decided to open new.
I've stuck with an issue below.
The target is to show xml attributes values on UI using soap message.
PHP code looks like:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://domain.com/xml/listener.asmx?WSDL");
$results = $client->ProductDescription(array('Username' => "anyuser", 'Password' => "anypassword", 'code' => "1108324"));
print_r($results);
```

As a result i get following message

```
stdClass Object ( [ProductDescriptionResult] => stdClass Object ( [any] => Imagehttp://catalog2.elkogroup.com/pictures/prDesc/large/1108324_425_0_425NULL.jpgDescription<h1 class="tagline"><span style="font-size: small">Quality surround audio for music, movies and games</span></h1> <p>&nbsp;Sound Blaster 5.1 VX is the absolute choice for those looking for better quality audio solutions basic motherboard audio can not deliver.</p>Vendor Homepagehttp://en.europe.creative.com/products/productarchive.asp?category=1&subcategory=873&product=17510&nav=Description2CREATIVE 5.1 VX (SB1071) OEMAudio-InInput/Output connectors1Audio-OutInput/Output connectors1MicrophoneInput/Output connectors1Included AccessoriesQuick start Guide; User Guide (on CD); Installation CDUnit Brutto Volumecubm0.001555Unit Net Weightkg0.13Unit Gross Weightkg0.157 ) )
```

The xml I get from soap ui using same request has different structure

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
      <ProductDescriptionResponse xmlns="https://ecom.elko.lv/xml">
         <ProductDescriptionResult>
            <NewDataSet xmlns="">
               <Product>
                  <Criteria>Image</Criteria>
                  <Value>http://test/</Value>
               </Product>
               ...
               ...
            </NewDataSet>
        </ProductDescriptionResult>
      </ProductDescriptionResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I was trying to read Criteria and Value argument values using different approaches, for example

a)

```
foreach($Envelope->Body->ProductDescriptionResponse->ProductDescriptionResult->NewDataSet->Product as $p)
        {
            echo $p->Criteria."<br>";
            echo $p->Value."<br>";
        }
```

Error message was "Undefined variable: Envelope..."

b)

```
foreach ($results->xpath('//soap:Envelope[1]/soap:Body[1]/ProductDescriptionResponse[1]/ProductDescriptionResult[1]/NewDataSet[1]/Product/*') as $item) 
        { print_r($item);}
```

Error message was Call to undefined method stdClass::xpath()

c)
Also tried to register namespace

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($results);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('envoy', 'https://ecom.elko.lv/xml');
```

...

But it says me that simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 to be string

etc...

Could you please help to figure out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it from the response element (`ProductDescriptionResult`), which is what the `SOAPClient` would give you:

```
echo $results->ProductDescriptionResult->NewDataSet->Product[1]->Criteria;
```

Keep in mind you don't have XML here anymore, the `SOAPClient` converted it to a nice tree of objects for you already. It could be that at any point the above trail doesn't exist (I just guessed it based on the XML), in that case, just do a `var_dump` from `get_object_vars` to see what's in the current node. Oh, and don't look at the HTML output in a browser, view the source, a lot of `<` and `>`s in your debug output can 'hide' content if you look at is as HTML.

---

**edit: this works here**

```
<?php
class S extends SoapClient {
        function __doRequest(){
                return  <<<XML
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
      <ProductDescriptionResponse xmlns="https://ecom.elko.lv/xml">
         <ProductDescriptionResult>
            <NewDataSet xmlns="">
               <Product>
                  <Criteria>Image1</Criteria>
                  <Value>http://test/1</Value>
               </Product>
               <Product>
                  <Criteria>Image2</Criteria>
                  <Value>http://test/2</Value>
               </Product>
            </NewDataSet>
        </ProductDescriptionResult>
      </ProductDescriptionResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
XML;
        }
}
$d = new S(null,array('uri' => 'localhost','location' => 'localhost'));
$result = $d->somerequest();
echo $result->NewDataSet->Product[0]->Criteria;
```

Comment: Thnaks you very much for fast response. I tried what you suggested but i still cant read the Criteria argument's value. The error message is Undefined property: stdClass::$NewDataSet. I've also check source as you suggested and there I could find xml structure. <NewDataSet xmlns=""><Product><Criteria>Microphone</Criteria><Value>Built-in</Value></Product></NewDataSet>

Comment: I've edited it in, but please... Make `var_dump` your friend, it tells you what variables are and what's in them.

Comment: var_dump returned following result.                         object(stdClass)[44]
  public 'ProductDescriptionResult' => 
    object(stdClass)[45]
      public 'any' => string '<NewDataSet xmlns=""><Product><Criteria>Image</Criteria><Value>http://catalog2.elkogroup.com/pictures/prDesc/large/1124919_425_0_425NULL.jpg</Value></Product><Product><Criteri... (length=5730)

Comment: I think i understand why. I tried to use echo $results->ProductDescriptionResult->any; And in this case i received this string. I should convert this string to XML and then i can read it properly...

Comment: Hm, it would be a weird thing to return unless the WSDL in use was not particularly decent... Does the above code work now, or are you still having problems?

Comment: I tried following and it works!    
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($results->ProductDescriptionResult->any);
  echo $xml->Product[0]->Criteria;

Comment: OK, a pity you have to re-interpret the XML (but PHP's SoapClient is famous for irritating misinterpretations, I don't think anything can be done about that at this time), but nice to hear you succeeded ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's great! Thanks a lot for support!